# Where do I ask about HTML and CSS?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

Where do I ask about HTML and CSS?

[Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) says they prefer not to have those, preferring questions that deal with sites as a whole, rather than specific details of individual pages or elements. Their FAQ says to ask on Stack Overflow, but I'm unsure if that is still the current norm.

HTML/CSS is quite a specific domain, incorporating programming and software development for sure, but also broadly reaching into design and graphic arts; the latter group is not well represented in the SO membership.

Comment: Well, don't ask "design and graphic arts" questions on Stack Overflow. Those don't have anything to do with CSS anyway, at least not *uniquely*. Questions regarding CSS *code* are on-topic for SO and should be asked there.

Answer (score 10):

Webmasters generally aren't the ones dealing with HTML/CSS coding unless they're also (frontend) web developers, who likely already have some participation on Stack Overflow anyway. I'm not surprised that HTML/CSS questions are generally off topic there.

> Their FAQ says to ask on Stack Overflow but I'm unsure if that is still the current norm

With hundreds of [html](/questions/tagged/html)[css](/questions/tagged/css) questions still showing up each day, I'm quite confident to say: **yes, it is.** And as [the #2 answerer of all time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/topusers) for [css](/questions/tagged/css) as of mid-2011, as well as a mod, you can trust my judgment on this.

Comment: I'm not so sure—I'm [the third answerer of all time](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows/topusers) for [tag:windows], and you can't trust my judgment at all!